# How to view address of register in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to debug calls to CreateFileA from a DLL that I do not have source code to.  I can set the breakpoint in the kernel32.dll with no problem, and I know that the value pointed to by (esp + 4) is the address of the filename.  What I'd like to do is to put a watch on the memory address pointed to by (esp + 4), however I cannot determine the correct watch syntax to use (providing it is even possible).  For example, I've tried various patterns to the following:

(char *)&(esp + 4) -- error: operand types bad for this operation

Obviously, I can always fall back on having two memory windows open and manually enter the addresses every time the debugger breaks, but I am going for efficiency here. :)

Comment: Did you try this:  `(char*)(esp+4)`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  It simply returns the byte pointed to at the memory location for (esp + 4).  So, if ESP is 0x01d00000 and the bytes at locations esp to (esp + 7) were "01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08", *(char *)(ESP + 4) would display 05.

Comment: oops... misread a * in your comment.  But I have tried the other way, too.  (char *)(esp + 4) treats the memory location as the contents of the string ( (char *)(esp + 4) == the bytes, 05 06 07 08 etc).  What I'm looking for is the contents of the address of esp + 4 (i.e. (char *)&0x08070605.)

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I'm pretty sure that (char*)0x08070605 is the answer you are looking for.  Visual Studio displays (char*) values as the pointer itself, and then the first few dozen characters of the string if it seems to be a string.  If you meant a pointer to a pointer, then try `*(char**)(esp+4)`