# Dereferencing pointers stored in registers (visual studio)

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, pointers, cpu-registers

I'm debugging an app and need to see the memory region pointed to by a value stored in `rcx`. Normally, for code, this would be done by selecting the variable (pointer) and adding a quick watch along with the number of elements to watch starting from the pointer:

[image: quickwatch]

I want to get the pointer to the string moved in `rcx` in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
000000013F1217C0  push        rbp  
000000013F1217C2  push        rdi  
000000013F1217C3  sub         rsp,0E8h  
000000013F1217CA  lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
000000013F1217CF  mov         rdi,rsp  
000000013F1217D2  mov         ecx,3Ah  
000000013F1217D7  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
000000013F1217DC  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
    goto mylabel;
000000013F1217DE  jmp         $mylabel (013F1217EEh)  
000000013F1217E0  jmp         $mylabel (013F1217EEh)  
    printf("Skipped\n");
000000013F1217E2  lea         rcx,[string "Skipped\n" (013F129C28h)]  
000000013F1217E9  call        printf (013F1211CCh)  
mylabel:
    printf("goto ftw!\n");
000000013F1217EE  lea         rcx,[string "goto ftw!\n" (013F129C38h)]  
000000013F1217F5  call        printf (013F1211CCh)  
    return 0xf00d;
000000013F1217FA  mov         eax,0F00Dh  
}
000000013F1217FF  lea         rsp,[rbp+0C8h]  
000000013F121806  pop         rdi  
000000013F121807  pop         rbp  
000000013F121808  ret
```

How may I get the value pointed to by rcx? In assembly, the syntax would be:

```
[rcx+index]
```

but how can I watch the value in visual studio?

I've tried adding:

```
[rcx]
[rcx],10
rcx,10
```

in QuickWatch, but for the first two entries I get:

type name is not allowed

and for the last I cannot dereference `rcx`, it is shown as before.

**Edit:**

Casting the value in the `rcx` to the desired type, works. In the above case a quick watch would be added on `(char*)rcx` shows the whole string in the debugging window. For other types (i.e. integers) it is also needed that the number of elements is also specified in the watch, otherwise only the first value is shown. For example, `(int*)rcx, 10` shows 10 four byte integers starting from the address value stored in `rcx`. The type must be adjusted for each data stored in the register.

Comment: I've not done this with registers before, but simply casting the value to the type you want to inspect it as should do the trick - e.g. `(char*)rcx`

Comment: That worked, but it has to be modified each time the type of dereferenced data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in "Watch #" window (menu `Debug > Windows > Watch > Watch #`), cast register to type "pointer to the *data type* of choice" and then dereference the result.
Example: dereference memory referenced by `rcx` and interpret it as 64bit unsigned integer:

```
*(size_t*) rcx
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the value of the register to a c/c++-pointer using _asm{....} then watch it  watch it as usual . 
here you can find how to access c variable from inline assembly :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08.aspx

Comment: I mustn't change the code. The high level _asm {} directive cannot be used.

Comment: this is the answer i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020232/how-to-view-address-of-register-in-visual-studio-debugger